# в select вывод значений столбца по имени, полученного из другого select. Оракл

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

помогите, пожалуйста!
Изучаю PL\SQL есть задача сравнить две таблицы.
Чтобы вручную не сравнивать и не прописывать все столбцы (их около 100 столбцов и 20 таблиц).
Как можно их подставить в select Оракла?
Я получила с помощью курсора название столбцов. Как название столбца column_name прописать в
`select column_name from emp` (вторая таблица соответственно emp2)? Где прописывается второй Select?
Структура например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    --Код курсора:
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare 
cursor curs is SELECT distinct column_name from all_tab_columns
where table_name='EMP' or table_name='EMP2';

v_column_name curs%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN curs;
LOOP
FETCH curs INTO v_column_name;
EXIT WHEN curs%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_column_name.column_name);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

За любую помощь буду очень благодарна, с переменными пока полное непонимание (на стадии набивания шишек).

Comment: *есть задача сравнить две таблицы* Что значит "сравнить таблицы"? в показанном примере они разные даже на глаз - только в одной есть поле `salary`.

Comment: Первое я сделала - сравнила структуры таблиц и написала что salary нет в таблице 1. теперь надо сравнить данные. То есть вывести что у Boris сменился адрес с Москвы на Лондон. Но загвоздка в том что столбцов 100. и все сравнивать их вручную нереально.

Comment: *загвоздка в том что столбцов 100. и все сравнивать их вручную нереально.* Oracle вполне себе поддерживает NATURAL JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test1 ( id INT, val VARCHAR(255));
> CREATE TABLE test2 ( id INT, val VARCHAR(255), grp INT);
> CREATE TABLE test3 ( id INT, val INT);
> ```

> ```
> -- имена полей различны, результат - различия
> SELECT column_name 
> FROM all_tab_columns
> WHERE table_name IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')
> GROUP BY column_name
> HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | COLUMN_NAME |
> | :---------- |
> | GRP         |
> ```

> ```
> -- имена полей полностью идентичны, результат пуст
> SELECT column_name 
> FROM all_tab_columns
> WHERE table_name IN ('TEST1', 'TEST3')
> GROUP BY column_name
> HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | COLUMN_NAME |
> | :---------- |
> ```

> ```
> -- имена полей полностью идентичны, а вот типы данных не совпадают, результат - различия
> SELECT column_name
> FROM all_tab_columns
> WHERE table_name IN ('TEST1', 'TEST3')
> GROUP BY column_name
> HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
>     OR COUNT(DISTINCT data_type) = 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> | COLUMN_NAME |
> | :---------- |
> | VAL         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e1852a658dc06de62554138227aa17a)*

---

> *теперь надо сравнить данные. То есть вывести что у Boris сменился адрес с Москвы на Лондон. Но загвоздка в том что столбцов 100. и все сравнивать их вручную нереально.* – Евгения Балабанова

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test1 ( id INT PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR(255));
> CREATE TABLE test2 ( id INT PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR(255));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test1
> SELECT 1, 'Иван' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, 'Дмитрий' FROM DUAL;
>
> INSERT INTO test2
> SELECT 1, 'Иван' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, 'Василий' FROM DUAL;
> ```

> ```
> -- Вывести id записей, которые не совпадают
> SELECT id
> FROM test1
> NATURAL FULL JOIN test2
> GROUP BY id
> HAVING COUNT(id) = 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03ff96a9e8fab78fa6a494e349bff38a)*

Comment: все гениально и просто! спасибо огромное! может подскажите - если надо вывести в чем именно разница? в столбце "имя"

Comment: @ЕвгенияБалабанова Не люблю я Оракл... тем более динамику в нём (и вообще динамику от структуры не уважаю - если оно потребовалось, то сразу возникает подозрение, что не всё ладно со архитектурой). Так что с динамикой возиться - увольте, а иного осмысленного способа не подскажу.

Comment: а я как не люблю... но приходится узнавать)

Comment: @ЕвгенияБалабанова Посмотрите, может, есть сравнительно несложный метод (функция), который сериализует всю запись целиком в XML или JSON? тогда несложно найти точку, где соответствующие сериализованные записи из разных таблиц не совпадают, не морочась с отдельными полями. Как я понимаю, речь идёт об одноразовом контроле данных? для такой задачи этого было бы достаточно имхо.